# QJSEngine global string compare

Tags: c++, qt, qjsengine

I am using Qt 5.11.2, in my application I am using QJSEngine, in my example I have a script:

```
    function connect() {
        console.info("-----------");
        if ( strFirstScan.localeCompare("true") == 0 ) {
            console.info("First scan");
            strFirstScan = "false";
            a = eval(a);
            b = eval(b);
            c = eval(c);
        }
        console.info("strFirstScan: " + strFirstScan + ", typeof: " + typeof strFirstScan); 
        console.info("a: " + a + ", typeof: " + typeof a);
        a++;
        console.info("b: " + b + ", typeof: " + typeof b);
        console.info("c: " + c + ", typeof: " + typeof c);
        console.info("-----------");
    }
```

I have connected this script to a button in the application, when I click the button the connect() function is called by the script.  I have registered some globals for use with the script:

```
    strFirstScan = "true"
    a = 123
    b = "Hello"
    c = {"a":1,"b":"A","c":{"aa":1}}
```

The output from the script application when the button is clicked is:

```
    2018-12-28 09:55:10.079663+0000 XMLMPAM[2470:247691] [js] -----------
    2018-12-28 09:55:10.079718+0000 XMLMPAM[2470:247691] [js] strFirstScan: "true", typeof: string
    2018-12-28 09:55:10.079742+0000 XMLMPAM[2470:247691] [js] a: 123, typeof: string
    2018-12-28 09:55:10.079775+0000 XMLMPAM[2470:247691] [js] b: 'hello', typeof: string
    2018-12-28 09:55:10.079804+0000 XMLMPAM[2470:247691] [js] c: {"a":1,"b":"A","c":{"aa":1}}, typeof: string
    2018-12-28 09:55:10.079832+0000 XMLMPAM[2470:247691] [js] -----------
```

I never see "First Scan" and the types of the variables remains string as it isn't getting to the eval statements.

Why isn't the compare working?  I've tried a number of alternatives:

```
    if ( strFirstScan == "true" ) {
```

and

```
    if ( strFirstScan.compare("true") == 0 ) {
```

None of these are any better, why isn't the compare working?

[Edit] I've modified the script to:

```
    function connect() {
        console.info("-----------");
        if ( typeof strFirstScan == "string" ) {
            console.info("First scan");
            console.info("strFirstScan: " + strFirstScan + ", typeof: " + typeof strFirstScan); 
            strFirstScan = 0;
            a = eval(a);
            b = eval(b);
            c = eval(c);
        }
        console.info("a: " + a + ", typeof: " + typeof a);
        a++;
        console.info("b: " + b + ", typeof: " + typeof b);
        console.info("c: " + c + ", typeof: " + typeof c);
        console.info("-----------");
    }
```

With the script like this I get the following in the output:

```
    2018-12-28 10:22:31.267553+0000 XMLMPAM[2993:335615] [js] -----------
    2018-12-28 10:22:31.267595+0000 XMLMPAM[2993:335615] [js] First scan
    2018-12-28 10:22:31.267629+0000 XMLMPAM[2993:335615] [js] strFirstScan: "true", typeof: string
    2018-12-28 10:22:31.267804+0000 XMLMPAM[2993:335615] [js] a: 123, typeof: number
    2018-12-28 10:22:31.267832+0000 XMLMPAM[2993:335615] [js] b: hello, typeof: string
    2018-12-28 10:22:31.267877+0000 XMLMPAM[2993:335615] [js] c: [object Object], typeof: object
    2018-12-28 10:22:31.267897+0000 XMLMPAM[2993:335615] [js] -----------
```

However if I add any comparison to the if condition comparing the string against "true" if does not pass into the first scan condition.

[Edit2] I modified my code that creates the global variable 'strFirstScan' to:

```
    pobjScriptEng->globalObject().setProperty("strFirstScan", QJSValue("true"));
```

This now resolves the problem and my script:

```
    if ( strFirstScan == "true" ) {
```

Works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code that creates the global variable 'strFirstScan' to:

```
pobjScriptEng->globalObject().setProperty("strFirstScan", QJSValue("true"));
```

This now resolves the problem and my script:

```
if ( strFirstScan == "true" ) {
```

This fixes the problem and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your program output, `strFirstScan` is not `true`, but rather `"true"`.

You can verify that by adding some sort of quotes around it's value in the log output.  I.e.: `console.info("strFirstScan: '" + strFirstScan + "', typeof: " + typeof strFirstScan);`

Here is the snippet to demonstrate your problem:

```js
var yourCase = '"true"';
console.info('value: ' + yourCase + ', type: ' + typeof yourCase + ', len: ' + yourCase.length);
console.info(yourCase === "true");

var youWant = 'true';
console.info('value: ' + youWant + ', type: ' + typeof youWant + ', len: ' + youWant.length);
console.info(youWant === "true");
```

Why exactly your code behaves as it does, however, is impossible to tell from what you've supplied.

Comment: Whats the difference?  I'm comparing the value of strFirstScan with "true".

Comment: In the output the type is shown as "string" and the value is "true".

Comment: @SPlatten you compare it with `true`, i.e. the string `true` (no double quotes), when it looks like (can't say for sure since you didn't provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) you have `"true"`, i.e. double quotes are part of the string. See your output for `b` (there it's the same, just with single quotes instead of double).

Comment: I am comparing it with a string literal, the quotes are around true making it a string.

Comment: @SPlatten your log indicates that `strFirstScan` is not `"true"` but `'"true"'`, i.e. the string containing double quotes. I don't know why, because from what you've supplied I can't reproduce it or even accurately guess what happens (what's with evals? Likely wrong).

Look at the line for `b` in your second log. `b: hello, typeof: string`, notice that `console.info` doesn't print extra quotes around `hello` even though `b === "hello"`, however it does for `strFirstScan` indicating that it's `strFirstScan === "\"true\""` for some reason.

Comment: I've fixed the problem now, I'll amend my question to include solution.

Comment: @SPlatten you could post it as another answer (in a day, IRC).